# How to set an "account" route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my routes, I have:

```
resources :users do
  resources :articles
end
```

Which will allow users to go to the following url to edit their profile settings:

```
http://localhost/users/foobar/edit
```

How can I make it so that the url will look like this instead:

```
http://localhost/account
```

I'd like users to edit their account details through this url instead: **http://localhost/account** and not **http://localhost/users/foobar/edit**.

At the same time, to display a user's articles. I need the url to be:

```
http://localhost/users/foobar/articles
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to create that route:

```
match 'account(/:id)' => 'users#edit'
```

with (/:id) if you need the user's id.

Comment: How would I prevent the user from going to **http://localhost/users/foobar/edit** ?

Comment: You can do a redirect to /account if they access the other url.